# Unable to access C-Array elements from outside the method that creates it

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, clion

While practicing for my Systems Programming course, I tried to create 2 dimensional array in one method and then fill the even places with 1's in another.
However neither passing the array as an argument nor making it a global variable worked.

Passed Argument Version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int rows;
int cols;


int* create (size_t r, size_t c)
{
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            *(arr + i*c + j) = 0;
            printf("%d",*(arr + i*c + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



}

void evenFill(int* array){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
           if(j%2==0){
                *(array + i*cols + j) = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArr(int* array){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
            printf("%d", *(array + i*cols + j));
        }
    }printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    rows = 5;
    cols = 5;
    int* array = create(rows, cols);
    evenFill(array);
    printArr(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Global Variable Version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int rows;
int cols;
int* array;

int* create (size_t r, size_t c)
{
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            *(arr + i*c + j) = 0;
            printf("%d",*(arr + i*c + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



}

void evenFill(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
           if(j%2==0){
                *(array + i*cols + j) = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArr(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
            printf("%d", *(array + i*cols + j));
        }
    }printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    rows = 5;
    cols = 5;
    array = create(rows, cols);
    evenFill();
    printArr();
    return 0;
}
```

Both variants terminate the program after the initial function calls to evenFill() with the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) apparently relating to illegal access.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You declare `create` to return an `int *`, but what does it actually return?

Comment: Always compile with warnings: `-Werror -Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 0):

In both versions the `create` function initializes a local variable.

If you want to properly pass it as an argument, you need to `return` it from the `create` function (which is currently missing - this should probably cause a compilation warning):

```c
int* create (size_t r, size_t c)
{
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            *(arr + i*c + j) = 0;
            printf("%d",*(arr + i*c + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return arr; /* This was missing */
}
```

If you want to use a global variable, you need to remove the type declaration in `create` so it stops hiding the global variable:

```c
int* create (size_t r, size_t c)
{
    arr = (int*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int)); /* Use the global variable */
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            *(arr + i*c + j) = 0;
            printf("%d",*(arr + i*c + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: dude i'm so stupid, tysm